# NSUserDefault Update Formula

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, nsuserdefaults, formula

Have a question on how can I update my formula by NSUserDefault. So I have two text field which needs to keep my Formula uptodate. So the user types in there number (value) then that numbers needs to go to my formula but the formula only showing me the distance value :).

Comment: The value doesn't get up to date in the formula it shows nil.

Comment: Please make sure you are saving right value type. According to apple reference the NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

Comment: Dude add some code fragments that you have tried, then we can help you to fix your issue...

Comment: @Programmer..., Which line shows the issue? Is it while saving to NSUserDefaults or while fetching it back? Have you tried adding NSLogs on these lines checked where exactly the issue is happening? Can you add NSLogs and update the question with the logs.

Comment: The issue is fetching the date to the the formula and i ran some NSLOG they are saying (null) then they show the value (25 and 4.15 ,I inputed 25 and 4.15 in the textfield in the simulator).

Comment: Your last comment is confusing -- when you do logs, you should update your code to show where you put them and what results you got. Saying they were null and then showed numbers is just useless to anybody trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with some changes. Here are my `.h` file and `.m` files. Try this.  Now also I didn't understand what your trying to find out, but this code gives me the values not a `nan`. While you writing code, don't forget to start your variable name in small letter that is a standard way. And also use `self` if you set a variable as property.

`ViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UITextFieldDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textGas;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textMoney;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textTotal;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textDistance;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

`ViewController.m`

```
 #import "ViewController.h"



    @interface ViewController ()
    {
        double totalDistance;
        float gas,money;
    }
    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize locationManager;


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

//set default value for Gas
        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Gas"]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1.0" forKey:@"Gas"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }

//set default value for Money
        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Money"]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1.0" forKey:@"Money"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }

        gas = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Gas"] floatValue];
        money =  [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Money"] floatValue];

        textGas.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",gas];
        textMoney.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",money];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Gas"])
            textGas.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Gas"];
        else
            textGas.text = @"0";//set default value

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Money"])
            textMoney.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Money"];
        else
            textMoney.text = @"0.01";//set default value



    }

    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [textMoney resignFirstResponder];
        [textGas resignFirstResponder];
    }

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
        }

    }
    #pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate
    -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {

        if ([textField.text intValue] == 0) {
            textGas.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",gas];
            textMoney.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",money];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                            message:@"Value cann't be zero."
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            alert = nil;
            return;
        }

        if (![textField.text length]) {
            textGas.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",gas];
            textMoney.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",money];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                            message:@"Value cann't be empty."
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            alert = nil;
            return;
        }

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if (textField == textGas) {
            [defaults setObject:textGas.text forKey:@"Gas"];
            gas = [textGas.text floatValue];
        }
        else if (textField == textMoney)
        {
            [defaults setObject:textMoney.text forKey:@"Money"];
            money = [textMoney.text floatValue];
        }
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    - (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
        {
            // Zoom to the current user location.
            MKCoordinateRegion userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 1200.0, 1200.0);
            [mapView setRegion:userLocation animated:NO];
            mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        }



        if (!oldLocation)
            totalDistance = 0.0;
        else
            totalDistance += [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];


        double distance = totalDistance*0.00062137119;
        textTotal.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", distance/gas*money];
        textDistance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f Miles", distance];

    }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @end
```

And the result in Simulator is 
[image: result in Simulator]

Don’t forget to connect `delegates` and `IBOutlet` from interface builder.[image: this is how you can check the delegate connection]

Comment: Thanks for the code but there is still a issue if the user wants to update there mpg and gas this code does't allow it (its shows the old value )...

Comment: @Programmer... type a value for mpg and gas then tap out side the keypad, it ll save the values.

Comment: @Programmer... i set minimum value for gas and mpg as 1.0. Try give some higher values

Comment: For Mainstoryboard should do something there… (Modals or Push)

Comment: @Programmer... in delegate `-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`, u can manage your max value

Comment: And also the texttotal textfield is showing me the distance value with your exact code...

Comment: if ([textField.text intValue] == 50)  I changed the number but same 1.0…

Comment: @Programmer... that because you might connected to wrong `IBOutlet`. Check your `IBOutlet` in interface builder

Comment: I posted the image want i getting in the simulator, i think you need edit your code...

Comment: @Programmer... change default value in `- (void)viewDidLoad` then remove app from device or simulator before you run.

Comment: where in the   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1.0" forKey:@"Money"]; or textGas.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",gas];

Comment: @Programmer... according to value you want to set. check the comment in the code. And i added an image that i got in simulator. check out

Comment: I want the user to set there mpg and money (is that possible)

Comment: The value don't save when quitting app

Comment: Why do we have to delete the app in the simulator to make the value to load :)

Comment: @Programmer... if you delete app, along with your app the `UserDefaults` of that app also will delete. so if you made any changes in `UserDefaults` structure it will reflect. Otherwise you may get errors.

Comment: So can we write a code were the user writes there mpg and money and save when the app quits...

Comment: @Programmer... for me this code save the values too.... have you connected your `UITextField`s `delegate` to `File' Owner` in interface builder?

Comment: @Programmer... check the image now

Comment: @Shinneeth Hamza Only issue in the code is loading the data the user inputs in the textfield...

Comment: Also i would like to use a button then a keyboard to update the NSUserDefault….

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may lie here:

```
int gas = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Gas"];
int money =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Money"];
```

You are writing out to your `NSUserDefaults` directly from your `textField.text`, often with `0.00` formatting, but you are reading it in as an `int`. It is stored as a `NSString` likely. You should store and read it as a `NSNumber`.

Going In:

```
NSNumber *foo = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:TextGas.text.integerValue];
NSNumber *bar = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:TextMoney.text.doubleValue];    
[defaults setObject:foo forKey:@"Gas"];
[defaults setObject:bar forKey:@"Money"];
```

Coming out:

```
NSNumber *gas = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Gas"];
NSNumber *money =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Money"];
gas.integerValue;
money.doubleValue;
```

Comment: reading/writing from `NSUserDefaults`. I'm confused as to what else you need.

Comment: I have shown you how to read/write safely from `NSDefaults`. It is your responsibility to take it from here. If you encounter a problem, post it, or better yet ask a TA or coworker.