# NSUserDefault in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a question on how can i use core date to update my formula. I have tried using NSUserDefault but the formula is blank (its saves though). So I have two textfields which  needs to update my formula. And when the user quits the app the two textfield date needs to be saved. So how should I approach this way…..

Comment: It's called CoreData, not CoreDate.

Comment: I made an edit again (could you +1 because I banned for asking questions and I asked the stackoverflow support that told me to edit bad questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Saving** the content of a text field to the user defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:field1.text forKey:@"field1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Loading** the content of a text field from the user defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
field1.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"field1"];
```

CoreDat**a** has little to do with saving simple things like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436817/nsuserdefault-update-formula I asked question on NSUerDefault updating Formula

Comment: What "formula" are you talking about?

Comment: You are trying to calculate something from the number entered in your text fields?

Comment: self.TextTotal.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", (totalDistance*0.000621371)/gas*money];
This is the formula the Gas and Money are ints with get update by a textfield which needs to update the formula and save the value when the application quits...

Comment: Yes.. I am trying to do that but the NSUserDefault does't update the formula but it does save when you quit the app.....

Comment: Yes the result does show but does't update the formula did you chack out the link it shows my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436817/nsuserdefault-update-formula

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19721/discussion-between-programmer-and-drummerb)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. And I'm not going to waste my time reading through a code dump of multiple pages, sorry. You don't even take the time to spell check your messages and use punctuation.

Comment: Well the issue with my code is that the NSUserDefault does't uptodate the formula its just blank but in the textfield its showing the value

Comment: I solved my promblem. It has to be converted to a float value to go to the formula. :)